# Error with Selenium and send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to fill an input with "Name"

```
driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout")
driver.find_element_by_id("order_billing_name").send_keys("Name")
```

This error appears:

```
Message: unknown error: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

This is the element `<input first_and_last="true" placeholder="full name" class="string required" type="text" name="order[billing_name]" id="order_billing_name">`

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Bot supreme/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("order_billing_name").send_keys("xdd")
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 351, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: can you share more of the stack trace?

Comment: Please read on how to provide an MCVE, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question to provide the missing information so we can help you

Comment: What version of Chrome/Selenium/Chromedriver are you on? Please Check [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to make sure you are on a compatible driver/chrome pair. Update Selenium to current versions as well. Please include your **entire** `Traceback` if possible instead of just the last line.

Comment: I updated everything and it didnt change anything and here is the trace https://pastebin.com/bC9yhhGg

Comment: Paste all required information in the question, not in an external resource. External resources may become inaccessible later, and I (for instance) can't access pastebin at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember this error occurring with **older** versions of Selenium.

Please run this to update your Selenium and try to run your test again:

`pip install -U selenium`

If you need more help to update *Selenium*, use [This](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) to learn more about how to install packages.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a working example of using **WebDriverWait** that should help:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout")
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='order_billing_name']")))
nameField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='order_billing_name']")
nameField.send_keys("Name")
```

For more information on how `WebDriverWait` works, use:

- https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: I updated selenium, chromedriver and reinstalled python and the error still comes out :(

Comment: With your code to add an item to cart beforehand of course

Comment: @A.Skoon, no problem! Glad it works. Happy programming ;).

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that when I open the URL you have provided, the site automatically redirects to a different page. (May be because you are not logged in or no items in the cart.)

If this is the case, then the element you are looking for not be in the new page.

Comment: Yes, you must add item to cart before

Comment: Yes. So every time you open a driver, a new browser instance is opened. So, the items previously added will not available on this new page and you have to write the script to add the items everytime from a different page before driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout")

Comment: add "from selenium import webdriver" before